# Nuxt 3 : How to redirect all 404 to home page with a 301 (SSR)

Tags: javascript, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301, nuxtjs3

I am searching how to catch all my 404 pages on my Nuxt 3 project and redirect them using a status code 301 to the home page (using SSR).

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple an clean solution, just by creating a global middleware.

For example, a file called `middleware/redirect-404.global.js` :

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  if (to.matched.length === 0) {
    return navigateTo('/', { redirectCode: 301 })
  }
})
```

> The `to.matched` is an array containing matching routes of your application. It is safe to say that if no route matches, then this is a 404 and should be redirect to the home page.

> You should append `.global` after your middleware name in order to include this middleware on all the requests.